# Replace only first instance of a character

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv

for example I have scv file which looks like

```
a1, b1, c1, d1
a2, b2, c2, d2
a3, b3, c3, d3
```

What I want to do is to replace the first comma `,` with the semicolon `;`. The position of first comma can be variable (`a` in the rows `n` and `m` can have different lengths). Finally my file shall look like

```
a1; b1, c1, d1
a2; b2, c2, d2
a3; b3, c3, d3
```

The other commas have to remain. Can somebody please tell me the most simple solution?

PS my solution doesn't work: `sed '/s/,/;/g' file.csv`

Comment: Do `sed 's/,/;/' file.csv` satisfy you?

Comment: no, I have got next error message: sed: -e expression #1, char 7: missing command

Comment: Do you miss quotes?

Comment: I have used already the sed command, but just with `/g` at the end - > `sed /s/,/;/g`. Your code produces by me an error message. Anyway, I'm not sure this code will change all the commas. I need to change only the firs one.

Comment: @Gufory, `g` is to change all comas. Without it, it changes only the first. See also `sed 's/,/;/2'` to change the second only and with GNU `sed`, `sed 's/,/;/2g'` to change all but the first.

Comment: With `g` sed change all commas in line, without it - just first. It cannot be true `sed "s/,/;/g"` do work and `sed "s/,/;/"` gets error. If you sence with **sed** try `while IFS=\, read a b ; do echo "$a;$b" ; done <file.csv`

Comment: Wow, this is exactly the solution! Now is everything works! Thank you a lot!

Comment: I"ve submitted an edit (peer-review pending) to change the title, as this explicitly is NOT about a specific position, but about the first occurrence, of the character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure **bash** solution

```
while IFS=\, read -r a b ; do echo "$a;$b" ; done <file.csv
```

Or just for fun

```
paste -d\; <(cut -d, -f1 file.csv) <(cut -d, -f1 --complement file.csv)
```

Comment: Try the first one on an input like `1,2,` or `1\,2` or `1`. See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for comment, I have *-r* option added.

Comment: good. That addresses `1\,2`, but not the `1,2,` or `1` cases though. Note that `,` is not special, you don't need to quote it.

Answer (score 17):

The `g` in:

```
sed 's/,/;/g'
```

is for *globally*, that is to substitute all occurrences of `,` with `;`.

If you want to do only one substitution per line, take off the `g`:

```
sed 's/,/;/'
```

And for completeness:

You can also specify which occurrence to substitute. For instance, to substitute only the second occurrence:

```
sed 's/,/;/2'
```

With GNU `sed`, you can also substitute all occurrences starting from the second one (in effect, all but the first one) with:

```
sed 's/,/;/2g'
```

To perform two substitutions, in this case:

```
sed 's/,/;/;s/,/;/'
```

Where it gets more complicated is when the pattern can match the substitution (or parts of it), for instance when substituting `,` with `<,>`. `sed` has no built-in mechanism to address that. You may want to use `perl` instead in that case:

```
perl -pe '$i = 0; s/,/$i++ < 2 ? "<,>" : $&/ge'
```

`perl -pe` is `perl`'s `sed` mode (note that the regex syntax is different). With the `e` flag of the `s///` operator, the replacement  is considered as code. There, we replace `,` with `<,>` only when our incremented counter is < 2. Otherwise, we replace the `,` with itself (`$&` actually referring to the matched string like `&` in `sed`'s `s` command).

You can generalise that for a range or set of substitutions. Like for 3<sup>rd</sup> to 5<sup>th</sup> and 7<sup>th</sup> to 9<sup>th</sup>:

```
perl -pe '$i = 0; s/,/$i++;
   $i >=3 && $i <= 5 || $i >= 7 && $i <= 9 ? "<,>" : $&/ge'
```

To replace only the first occurrence *in the whole input* (as opposed to *in each line*):

```
sed -e 's/,/;/;t done' -e b -e :done -e 'n;b done'
```

That is, upon the first successful substitution, go into  a loop that just prints the rest of the input.

With GNU `sed`, you can use the *pseudo address 0*:

```
sed '0,/,/s//;/'
```

---

### Note

I suppose it's a typo, but the

```
sed '/s/,/;/g'
```

command you wrote in your question is something completely different.

That's doing:

```
sed '/start/,/end/g'
```

where `start` is `s` and `end` is `;`. That is, applying the `g` command (replace the pattern space with the content of the hold space (empty here as you never hold anything)) for sections of the file in between one that contains `s` and the next one that contains `;`.

Comment: Note that to only replace 1st occurence in a file (not in a line) you need to do something else. See:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-substitute-only-a-first-match-occurrence-using-sed-command

Comment: @Nux. Thanks, I've added a section about that.