# Removing the first space in a line

Tags: bash, text-processing

How can I remove only the first space from a line like the one below without removing the other spaces in the same line?

Example Input:

```
2015-04-18 10:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000
```

Example Output:

```
2015-04-1810:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000
```

Comment: [Replace only first instance of a character](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298139)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may use `sed` for this:

```
sed 's/ //' infile >outfile
```

This applies a substitution to all lines of the file `infile` that will substitute the first space character with nothing (i.e. remove it). The output is stored in the file `outfile`.  With `sed 's/ //N'`, where `N` is an integer between 1 and 9, you can pick which space to remove.

If the line is in a shell variable, you could use

```
var="${var/ /}"
```

This uses the `${parameter/pattern/string}` parameter expansion in `bash` to do the same thing as the `sed` command, but on the value in `$var`. The resulting string is, in this example, then stored back into `$var`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
> awk '{print $1$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' yourfile > outputfile
```

The output:

```
> cat outputfile

2015-04-1810:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000
```

You can remove any space in the line and keep any one

**Assuming**: Input file must contain:

1. no leading whitespace
2. no consecutive spaces
3. no tabs
4. less than seven spaces total

If any of this assumption are violated, the result **will not be correct**

Comment: Downvoted because this is utterly dependent on the following assumptions: Input file must contain (1) no leading whitespace (2) no consecutive spaces (3) no tabs (4) less than seven spaces total.  If *any* of these assumptions are violated, the command does something quite different from the requested action: "Remove the first space from each line (without other changes)."

Comment: The proper solution [has been posted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339270/135943).  This answer is really not correct.

Comment: @Wildcard in general you are right, if any of the assumptions that you mention are violated this answer will not be right, and i totally agree with you that the other answer is the best answer, but, that doesn't mean that is not a right answer for this condition.

Comment: Keep in mind that this site exists to serve *future* readers, not just the current asker.  So this is a very misleading answer to, "How do I remove the first space from each line of my file?"  At the very least you should include the assumptions after the answer with a note, **warnings.**

Comment: @Wildcard again you are right, I edited my answer.

Comment: Instead of all this verbosity, you could have used `sub()` function, which removes only first match in line, so your lengthy awk expression can be reduced to `awk '{sub(/ /,"")};1'  input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/ //|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

Small and simple Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -ane 'printf "%s",@F[0];@F[0]="";print @F'  <<< "2015-04-18 10:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000"                        
2015-04-1810:21:591005430-9999-9999000000000000
```

Or even simpler as suggested by mik in comments:

```
perl -pe 's/ //' <<< "2015-04-18 10:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000"
```

Python can do it too. Here's a small script that does the job. It can be reduced to a one-liner, if necessary:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    words=line.strip().split()
    print(words[0],end="")
    print(" ".join(words[1:]))
```

And with the same line in input file duplicated 3 times, here's a test for multi-line input:

```
$ ./remove_leading_space.py < input.txt                                                                                               
2015-04-1810:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000
2015-04-1810:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000
2015-04-1810:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000
```

If you just one single line edited, you can do it like so:

```
$ ./remove_leading_space.py <<< "2015-04-18 10:21:59 10 05430 -9999 -9999 000000000000"
```

Comment: A small and simple `perl` oneliner would be `perl -pe 's/ //'`

Comment: @mik Thank you. Edited into the answer. Still learning perl, so doing best I can with what i got :)

Answer (score -1):

It's a quite simple question.

`sed -i 's/ //' /path/to/file`

Try this command and don't add **s** in the end of sed expression.

It will just remove the first space each line.

Comment: How's this different than Kusalananda's ?

Comment: @don_crissti while by using `-i` you can type less. And `-i` is the official recommended way if you just wanna change text files directly.

Comment: Yeah, next guy will add a `-e` and say it's different too...

Comment: @don_crissti Why not? I think it will provide more helpful information for those people who are in trouble like the questioner.